# void functions with no arg vs returing functions with argh

Tags: performance, return, local, private, void

say you have to code a sw in c++/java, in which of the two ways below would you choose to implement most of the functions?

```
void function(){
  //code which uses private/public class variables
  //it modifies directly variable outside of the function
}

xyztype function(a,b,c,d){
  //code which uses local variables and args
  xyztype xyz;
  return xyz;
}
```

My question is in terms of:

```
1. Performance
2. Good practice in terms of perfomance
```

I don't care about readability/usability or anything similar.
At school we were used to code the second way, but now i tend to use 9/10 times the first method.
Clearly local variables are faster but what if i have 40 functions acting on 5 variables? Declearing everything locally maybe could be counterproductive

Comment: I know nobody in the Java - community that believes that this has a relevant performance impact in ordinary code. There might be an impact in code that is called very often and is performance critical, but a best practice says that such optimizations should be done after programming and spotting a bottleneck with measurements. You can always use the first way to write Java code, but it will be considered to smell by most members of the Java-community, especially if you make fields public for it.

Answer (score 0):

Performance is not always the first thing to deal with ( while your code is not performance critical ) .
For serious projects you want your code to be clear and to follow a specific paradigm to make later development easy  .
A functions that accesses global variables is used for procedural programming  paradigm  ( like in pascale , assembly ... ) and adding some code later will be so hard if you follow that method , and that's why it is recommended to use  Object Oriented Programming .

A procedure is a function that has no return value , so that is what you are talking about .

And about passing arguments , you don't really want to let a function acess global variables for many reasons :

- you  want to write a function once and port it later to an other project where  the global variables have diffrent names .
- you want a function call be followed by a list of variables that gives you an idea of what the function does when you want to make some changes .

  consider this example , to rotate a segment , there are two possibilities  , rotate it over a point in the plan , or rotate over it's center , but both function calls using that method will look like this 'roate_line()'
  so you can 't really guess the case .
- An other reason is that you can use the function to apply changes for  specific set of variables only  , and your code won't be dynamic , you actually have to implement a function for each set of variables to apply the same type of treatment  , ( 10 functions to rotate 10 segments !!! )

But talking about performance , passing arguments is done through the stack , and each passed argument requires a push and pop instructions and a memory access so basicly a tiny bit slower ( stack based computer - like most modern ones - are actually very very fast in doing it  ) , so you won't really notice the difference , noting that many programmers fix the issue by passing a pointer of a structure , so that one variable only will be passed ( the address) and not the whole structure